Circular dependency in NestJS
I have a module within NestJS where I need services to include each other. So, I have a circular dependency. According to NestJS documentation, I used @ForwardRef:

but running the project still ended up with an error:

I understand that the problem is during the import itself, and NestJS doesn't start at all. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution for this problem anywhere.
Can you please help?
I've tried searching the internet, asking GPT-4o and GitHub Copilot, unfortunately, without success.

It worked in conjunction with ModuleRef for me (https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#moduleref-class-alternative)
category.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => TagModule)],
  providers: [CategoryService],
  exports: [CategoryService],
})
export class CategoryModule {}

category.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
   constructor(
      @Inject(forwardRef(() => TagService))
      private readonly tagService: TagService,
   ) {}
 }

tag.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => CategoryModule)],
  providers: [TagService],
  exports: [TagService],
})
export class TagModule {}

tag.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class TagService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CategoryService))
    private readonly categoryService: CategoryService,
  ) {}
}

UPDATE
If both services with a circular dependency belong to the same module, just use forwardRef in the services with the circular dependency
blog.module.ts
@Module({
  controllers: [BlogController],
  providers: [BlogService, TagService, CategoryService],
})

blog.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class BlogService {
  constructor(
    private readonly tagService: TagService,
    private readonly categoryService: CategoryService,
  ) {}

tag.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class TagService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CategoryService))
    private readonly categoryService: CategoryService,
  ) {}
}

category.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => TagService))
    private readonly tagService: TagService,
  ) {}
}


Thanks for this idea, but I can't use forwardRef with the module because I don't have Tag and Category modules. Tag and Category services are both part of a Blog module. I totally forgot to write this to my question.

Than its even simpler. You would like to use constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => TagService)) private readonly tagService: TagService) {} in CategoryService and constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => CategoryService))  private readonly categoryService: CategoryService) {} in TagService
Than in the service where you want to import them both you use regular import constructor(     private readonly tagService: TagService,     private readonly categoryService: CategoryService,   ) {} e.g. in BlogService

I tried it, but I ended up in the same situation.  I think the problem is in the imports themselves because NestJS app didn't start at all. The reference error shown on the second screenshot appears (error in internal/modules/cjs/loader), and that's all. No Nest error.....

Its hard to say for sure what causes issue on your end with the limited info shared.
If I were you I would debug it as follows

Make sure you do not inject interface  as a dependency. TS does not leave any metadata about interfaces and thus you should never use interface as a provider token
install madge (https://github.com/pahen/madge) and check for all circular dependencies npx madge dist/main.js --circular
Try to create new modules with the minimal functionality as in the response to your question (since it is tested and works) and add additional functionality gradually.


You need to cover both parts of the relationship, if the services have a circular dependency you should also the the forward ref in CategoryService and in TagService
You can read the second part of the forward reference where it says this
https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#forward-reference
Another issue could be that you have a module circular dependency instead of a service circular dependency which is slightly different, but according to your question this is not the case

I followed these instructions (https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#forward-reference) and set it up that way in my project. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.
